# Whats the best distribution Linux to use in a USB Persistent?

Tags: boot, usb, xubuntu, wine

i would like to know wich is the best distribution to use in USB 3.0, i would like to use Linux in computers to show some one how is it working and how easy is to use Linux, i try to use Ubuntu but cant install for example Wine, i try to install XUbuntu but not boot from USB.

Some one now which one is the best? i got USB 3.0 Sandisk 32gb SDCZ43

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Wine might not be available for live USB , but don't quote me on that. Also , your question is pretty much asking for opinion-based questions, which means this question will be closed soon.  I'd say , try Ubuntu Gnome or Lubuntu.  In my experience Ubuntu USB can be slow (because the default desktop is a little bit resource-heavy ), but Gnome works like charm for the 90% of cases.

Comment: Note a few things: if you're just burn LiveUSB to usb, then obviously whatever you installed would never be saved after reboot, as it is only in RAM. You need rather install a distro to usb stick, however in this case you have to make some tweaking with regard to moving thru `fstub` every log and temporary directory to RAM — otherwise you system might be incredibly slow because of the slow IO of USB sticks. Make a search along keywords something like `install linux to stick`, and pay attention to improving performance tricks.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the information you supply there is no "best".

- "wine" is the same on any Ubuntu version so not usable for comparison.
- "booting from usb" is a generic BIOS option, depends on a correctly burned installer but that is about it.

"wine" is a hassle on a normal installation. It will perform even worse on a live session. I would avoid it at any cost anyways and opt for "steam" if you want to show a gaming experience. Or even stick with the gaming section. Mind that gaming requires a well working system. A live session is not the best setup for it.

If you want people to experience the power of Ubuntu I would argue you should use Ubuntu (Unity), kUbuntu (KDE), Ubuntu Mate. The other versions are intended for lower end systems so do not give a *full experience*. In general they drop graphics, animations and use applications that have a lower power consumption.

It would be better to use a notebook and not a live session.